# how to update field in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I have a field that type is array in mongoose, I want to push a value into the array by match query.
my below approach is wrong, cannot use goods: goods.push(). 
can anybody help me how to do that? thanks.

```
UserModel.update({_id: {$in: ids}}, { $set: { goods: goods.push(goodsid) }}, callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a approach that is $addToSet can fix it.